# Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, windows-server

I would kindly like to ask for help an issue I have running selenium on on a windows server without an interface, I get the following error:

> Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:49906/    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.DriverService.Start()    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command
>   commandToExecute)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String
>   driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities
>   desiredCapabilities)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor
>   commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service,
>   ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeOptions options)

Comment: ran it in headless mode and I still get the error

Comment: As stated, please show us your code.

Answer (score 1):

Changed my Target Framework to .NET Core 2.1 (previously set to .net core 3.0)
now its working.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56712777/openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-cannot-start-the-driver-service-on-http-l):

When the service start the only things executed are a process with the driver service and an api call to that service.
The problems that can rise could be:

- you can't execute the process, because the executable is not reachable

  - executable not there
  - wrong permissions
- some configurations are preventing you from executing successfully the api call and reach http://localhost:60623/

  - proxy settings (adding `NO_PROXY` environment variable excluding `localhost` might help)
  - firewall settings
  - port already used

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was because there are too many background chrome process running. Run cmd as admin and use `taskkill /f /im chromedriver.exe` to kill all chrome driver instances and use `taskkill /f /im chrome.ext /t` to kill all chrome instances made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Browser opened with Selenium requires to run in Session 0 (GUI interface in Windows). Most possible that error that you provided is references to this problems.

You can try to solve Session 0 problem with running browser in headless mode, as it doesn't require to render in UI.

How to do it you can check it with this link [Headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)

Comment: I ran it in headless mode and I still get the error

Comment: After some research in the internet I found that similar problem was registered in Selenium GitHub. Can you please check if this solution will work for you [OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost/](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5293) 


If this solution does not work can you please provide source code for you WebDriver initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Having a VPN client running? In order to fully isolate (for amateurs), the loopback both as Ip and/or hostname are not directly accessible (unless the client is giving a possibility to exclude localhost or 127.0.0.1(and its Ipv6 equivalent) - was freaking me out once like crazy when i couldnt get the driver to work just because I still had my Cyberghost client running, but back to the most likely reason:

Especially when working a lot with ports, and possibily a ton of drivers, manually managing ports or at least manually checking/setting the port for the driver service can help.

I do this like this: I get all currently active TcpConnections(local endpoints). I create a random port from a given range for the driver service until the assigned port is not currently being used.

```
var ipGlobalProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
var tcpConnInfoArray = ipGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections();
do
{
   driverService.Port = Random.Next(29999,65535);
} while (tcpConnInfoArray.Any(d => d.LocalEndPoint.Port == driverService.Port));
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Selenium hosts a webserver on the localhost, which is not accessible. I **disabled using a proxy for local addresses**, and this solved the problem.